# Selecting data and count from another table at the same time

Tags: mysql

I just want to echo the articles and Order it by the most number it has been commented by users. This are my two tables

tbl_articles

```
article_id  |  articles_title  |
 1          |     This is 1st  |
 2          |     This 2nd    |
```

tbl_comment:

```
comment_id  |   user_id     | article_id | comment_msg
 1          |       1       |    1       | my comment1
 2          |       1       |    2       | my comment2
 3          |       2       |    1       | some comment1
```

How to join these tables and force a result like this

```
 article_id|articles_title|  comment_count  |
     1     |  This is 1st |    2            |
     2     |  This 2nd    |    1            |
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to also order the results by comment_count, i.e. have the most-commented article first in the result list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query below uses `INNER JOIN` which will only display all articles on the result if it has atleast `1` comment. If you want to display articles even without comment yet, change `INNER JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.article_ID,
        a.article_title,
        COUNT(*) Comment_Count
FROM    articles a
        INNER JOIN comment b
            ON a.article_ID = b.article_ID
GROUP   BY a.article_ID, a.article_title
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (using `INNER JOIN`)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa86c/3)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (using `LEFT JOIN`)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37145/2)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: works fine, thanks. I'm already new to sql joins, thanks for the links

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple join query with an aggregation:

```
select article_id, articles_title, count(c.comment_id) as comment_count
from tbl_articles a left outer join
     tbl_comment c
     on a.article_id = c.article_id
group by article_id, articles_title
```

This uses a `left outer join` to keep all the articles, even when they have no comments.

Comment: thaks. I just don't know where to add the count part in the join